# SQLFilter based on System Properties in Azure Service Bus Subscription

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am working on setting up a topic/subscription service, and need help with the syntax of my SQLFilter so I can access BrokeredMessage Properties, specifically the To property. What is the correct syntax on a SQL Filter to access the System Properties of the message?

I have a working example using this tutorial where I can send and receive to my topic/subscriptions as desired: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions/

However, now I want to setup SQL filters for each subscription based on the To property of the BrokeredMessage. The tutorial I followed mentions that it is possible "When a subscription is created, you can supply a filter expression that operates on the properties of the message, both the system properties (for example, Label) and custom application properties (for example, StoreName.)"

If I set a custom property, e.g. StoreName, like this:

```C#
message.Properties.Add("StoreName", "TestMe");
```

and set the subscription up with a SQL Filter like this:

```C#
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription("MyNSTestTopic", "TestSubscription", new SqlFilter("StoreName = 'TestMe'"));
```

The subscription filters as expected. However, if I try and use the BrokeredMessage objects To property (or label for that matter) as described in the article, I have been unable to get it to work. I've tried the following SQL Filters with no luck. What is the correct syntax to access the System Properties of the message?

```html
BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage();
message.To = "TestMe";

namespaceManager.CreateSubscription("MyNSTestTopic", "TestSubscription", new SqlFilter("To = 'TestMe'"));
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription("MyNSTestTopic", "TestSubscription", new SqlFilter("Message.To= 'TestMe'"));
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription("MyNSTestTopic", "TestSubscription", new SqlFilter("MessageTo= 'TestMe'"));
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription("MyNSTestTopic", "TestSubscription", new SqlFilter("messageto= 'TestMe'"));
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From this article [Topic Subscription Filters](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging/TopicFilters):

> **SQL Filters** - A `SqlFilter` holds a [SQL-like condition expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.sqlfilter.sqlexpression.aspx) that is evaluated in the broker against the arriving messages' user-defined properties and system properties. **All system properties (which are all properties explicitly listed on the [BrokeredMessage class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage_properties.aspx)) must be prefixed with `sys.` in the condition expression**. The SQL subset implements testing for existence of properties (`EXISTS`), testing for null-values (`IS NULL`), logical `NOT`/`AND`/`OR`, relational operators, numeric arithmetic, and simple text pattern matching with `LIKE`.

So in your case you need to create a `SqlFilter` on the `sys.To` property:

```
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription("MyNSTestTopic", "TestSubscription",
    new SqlFilter("sys.To = 'TestMe'"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the link Thomas, using sys.To worked perfectly.

Comment: Unfortunately the azure docs left this important note out of the sql filter docs. Thanks.

Comment: How do you express a user-defined property in the filter?

Comment: @JimAho, you mean something like `sys.To = MyCustomProperty` or `MyCustomProperty = 'TestMe'` ?

Comment: Yes, this one: `MyCustomProperty = 'TestMe'`

Comment: something like `new SqlFilter("MyCustomProperty  = 'TestMe'")`

Answer (score 1):

For Custom Properties use the **`user.`** prefix from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-sql-filter#:%7E:text=The%20user%20value%20indicates%20user%20scope%20where%20%3Cproperty_name%3E%20is%20a%20key%20of%20the%20custom%20properties%20that%20you%20can%20set%20on%20the%20message%20when%20sending%20to%20Service%20Bus.)

```
user.StoreName = 'TestMe'
```